# DNN - MappedPath is empty when updating a folder

Tags: dotnetnuke

Everytime i update one of my folders the mapped path of my folder becomes suddenly empty and i can't find a method to resolve to change it or add a new mapped path to it.

This is my code:

```
         // Folder information
        var folderInfo = new FolderInfo();
        folderInfo.PortalID = base.PortalId;
        folderInfo.FolderPath = txtEditFolderName.Text;
        folderInfo.FolderID = Convert.ToInt16(Request.QueryString["eventID"]);
        folderInfo.DisplayPath = txtEditFolderName.Text;
        folderInfo.DisplayName = txtEditFolderName.Text;
        folderInfo.FolderMappingID = 9;

        // Update folder
        FolderManager.Instance.UpdateFolder(folderInfo);

        // Move folder
        FolderManager.Instance.MoveFolder(folderInfo, txtEditFolderName.Text);

        // TODO: REMOVE OLD DIRECTORY

        // Add new directory
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderInfo.PhysicalPath);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the mappingId from another portal, that was causing the problem.
When i used the mappingId from the right portal it worked.